# DialoguFlow Network request not working in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, dialogflow-es

I found some weird issue in my code. Would you people help me out. I followed the tutorials in the same pattern,I was unable to figure out.

This is my code.

```
    let request : AITextRequest = ApiAI.shared().textRequest()

    if let text = message?.text, text != "" {
        request.query = text
        print("Hey : \(text)")
    } else {
        print("return")
        return
    }

    request.setMappedCompletionBlockSuccess({ (request, response) in
        let response = response as! AIResponse
        if let textResponse = response.result.fulfillment.messages {
            print("\(textResponse)")
        }
    }, failure: { (request, error) in
        print(error!)
    })
```

It didn't entered into the completionBlock. It was not showing an error in the failure also.

Comment: Try to print something when `response.result.fulfillment.messages` is `nil`

Comment: It is not entering into the block, that was the issue.

Comment: What is realization of `setMappedCompletionBlockSuccess`. Can you add code please.

Comment: I didn't get it , what does it mean!

Comment: Please check this tutorial code once... FYI https://www.appcoda.com/chatbot-dialogflow-ios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution for this. I know this is very strange.

I have initialized the CLIENT_TOKEN in Appdelegate. It was not working in my class.
So, I have initialized it in the same class where I was using this methods. It started firing the API.

```
   //ViewDidLoad
   let configuration = AIDefaultConfiguration()
    configuration.clientAccessToken = "*********************" //Hidden
    let apiai = ApiAI.shared()
    apiai?.configuration = configuration
```